# Mule standalone (command line) cant find a file in its classes folder

Tags: java, maven, eclipse-plugin, mule, mule-component

I have a mule flow in `Project B` that references a Java component in `Project A`. The projects are structured in the following manner.

```
Project A
   src/test/java-ComponentClass
   src/test/resources- propertyfile.properties
 Project B(Mule project)
   src/main/app(Flows)- testflow(flow with component referencing ComponentClass)
   src/main/resources - propertyfile.properties
```

`testFlow` creates the component class bean in the following manner .

```
 <spring:beans>

        <spring:bean id="beanA"   class="com.packagename.ComponentClass"/>
    </spring:beans>
```

The following segment shows how the `ComponentClass` accesses the propertyfile.

```
propFilePath="src/test/resources/propertyfile.properties"
File propFile = new File(propFilePath);
if(!propFile.exists())// To handle mule flow as mule doesnt bundle src/test/resources
{
   propFilePath=this.getClass().getResource("/propertyfile.properties");
   // points to /usr/local/mule/mule-enterprise-standalone-3.6.0-M2/apps/ProjectB-1.0-SNAPSHOT/classes/propertyfile.properties -for standalone.- 1
  //propFilePath="propertyfile.properties". <--eclipse-mule plugin-2

}

//process the file from its path--
```

`Project A` has been compiled in such a way that its test classes are accessible. `Project B` imports the test-jar from `Project A` through its pom.

Now when I try to run the flow through the mule standalone on my system after building the project. The project fails to deploy on mule throwing a nested exception that the `propertyfile` is missing and hence the bean creation for `ComponentClass` has failed. However, upon inspecting the path location in 1-(within the zip) I find that the file actually exists within the classes folder. Any thoughts whats happening and how I could fix it?

Also when I place the file in the base folder of `ProjectB` and provide the path as in line -`2` there seem to be no problems when I run the project off the mule runtime in eclipse but this fails when I try to deploy to the standalone.

Any feedback or suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyhow, mule leverages a hyerarchical classpath isolating intentionally the applications to reduce clashing. Please, read this [document](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Classloader+Control+in+Mule) to understand it better.

If what you have is some kind of shared utility, why not just create a common project that creates a jar and then just have both projects to depend on it?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Based on your first sentence.. Are you saying that I cant have `ComponentClass` in `ProjectA` access a resource inside `classes` of Project B? The path resolves to the right file, which is baffling.

Comment: As for the second comment, ProjectA is a shared utility class that has .jar file in the mule project(with the file). Can I pass a path to that ? What would the path to that be?

Comment: An ESB container will do its best to isolate apps (as in David A Chappell's Enterprise Service Bus book chapter 6).

So technically there should be no shared parts but libraries. Those shared libraries could be placed either in lib/user or even included in both apps.

Comment: Precisely.But the particular file that I mention is placed in `src/main/resources` of `Project B` (so it gets put on the classpath) and its also included in ProjectA (whose jar is within ProjectB).How do I access it then?

Comment: If the class is in the classpath it should be as simple as using [IoUtils](https://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/util/IOUtils.html#getResourceAsString(java.lang.String, java.lang.Class)). With the normal classloader.

Comment: The  file(`propertyfile.properties`) is on the claspath. And the class making the call from ProjectA- `ComponentClass` is in a jar within `lib` inside projectB. Are you implying that I do something like `propFile= this.getClass.getResourceAsUrl("/propertyfile.properties");` in `ComponentClass`? It'd be great if you could make it part of the answer as Im very new to Mule.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm confused. Please just try this option that will hopefully suit your needs: The conf folder of the distrubution is on the classpath, could you please copy the properties file there and try opening a resource `propertyfile.properties` on the root of the classpath. We'll move on from there.

Comment: Where exactly is the `conf` folder ? I see only the lib and classes folder within the .zip folder..

Comment: In the root of the mule standalone.